# jQgrid - Change Edit button icon when including Edit button on every line

Tags: jqgrid, icons

Simply put:  When I include the Edit button on every row of the grid, how can I adjust which icon is used?  I am able to do this when leveraging the Edit button down in the Nav Grid, but I'm having no luck changing it when it is included in every row.  Here is what I was attempting with the "buttonicon" option:

```
    $("#listAllSupplierPurchasesGrid").jqGrid({
        url: "/TargetItems/GetAllPurchasesAllSuppliers",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',
        colNames: ['PurchaseId', 'Supplier', 'Item', 'Price', 'Qty', 'Total', 'Payment Method', 'Payment Status', 'Create Date', ' '],
        colModel: [
            {
                key: true,
                name: 'PurchaseId',
                index: 'PurchaseId',
                editable: true,
                search: false,
                hidden: true
            },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'Supplier',
                index: 'Supplier',
                width: 300,
                search: true,
                stype: 'select',
                searchoptions: {
                  dataUrl: '/WantedItems/GetSupplierOptionList'
                }
            },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'WantedItem',
                index: 'WantedItem',
                width: 300,
                search: true,
                stype: 'select',
                searchoptions: {
                    dataUrl: '/WantedItems/GetWantedItemsOptionList'
                }
            },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'WantedItemPrice',
                index: 'WantedItemPrice',
                editable: false,
                search: false,
                width: 80,
                formatter: 'currency',
                formatoptions: {
                    prefix: '$',
                    thousandsSeparator: ',',
                    decimalPlaces: 2
                }
            },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'QuantityPurchased',
                index: 'QuantityPurchased',
                editable: false,
                search: false,
                width: 50
            },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'TotalPrice',
                index: 'TotalPrice',
                editable: true,
                editoptions: {
                    readonly: 'readonly'
                },
                search: false,
                width: 80,
                formatter: 'currency',
                formatoptions: {
                    prefix: '$',
                    thousandsSeparator: ',',
                    decimalPlaces: 2
                }
            },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'PaymentMethod',
                index: 'PaymentMethod',
                editable: true,
                editoptions: {
                    readonly: 'readonly'
                },
                search: false,
                width: 120
            },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'PaymentStatus',
                index: 'PaymentStatus',
                width: 100,
                search: true,
                stype: 'select',
                searchoptions: {
                    dataUrl: '/WantedItems/GetPaymentStatusOptionsList'
                }
            },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'CreateDate',
                index: 'CreateDate',
                editable: false,
                search: false,
                width: 80,
                formatter: 'date',
                formatoptions: {
                    newformat: 'm/d/Y'
                }
            },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'CompletePayment',
                index: 'CompletePayment',
                width: 30,
                editable: false,
                search: false,
                sortable: false,
                formatter: 'actions',
                formatoptions: {
                    keys: true,
                    editformbutton: true,
                    editbutton: true,
                    delbutton: false,
                    buttonicon: "ui-icon-circle-check",
                    editOptions: {
                        editCaption: "Complete Payment",
                        bSubmit: "Mark as Paid",                            
                        closeOnEscape: true,
                        closeAfterAdd: true,
                        viewPagerButtons: false,
                        closeAfterEdit: true,
                        url: '/TargetItems/CompletePayment'
                    }
                }
            },
        ],
        pager: jQuery('#listAllSupplierPurchasesGridPager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        height: '100%',
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Payments and Purchases',
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false
        },
        height: "100%",
        multiselect: false
    })
    .filterToolbar();
```

The only method I've found that works is to simply add a jQuery function in the gridComplete() event to remove / replace the class on the SPAN in question.  I have a suspicion that jqGrid has a better method for handling this.  Here was the jQuery solution that works currently for reference.

```
        gridComplete: function()
        {
            $("td[aria-describedby='listAllSupplierPurchasesGrid_CompletePayment'").find('.ui-icon-pencil').removeClass('ui-icon-pencil').addClass("ui-icon-circle-check");                
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid don't allow to configure icons added by `formatter: "actions"`. So you have to change it inside of `localComplete`

```js
$("#grid").bind("jqGridLoadComplete jqGridAfterInsertRow", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find(">tbody>.jqgrow>td div.ui-inline-edit")
        .html("<span class=\"" + $.jgrid.nav.editicon + "\"></span>");
    $this.find(">tbody>.jqgrow>td div.ui-inline-del")
        .html("<span class=\"" + $.jgrid.nav.delicon + "\"></span>");
    $this.find(">tbody>.jqgrow>td div.ui-inline-save")
        .html("<span class=\"" + $.jgrid.nav.saveicon + "\"></span>");
    $this.find(">tbody>.jqgrow>td div.ui-inline-cancel")
        .html("<span class=\"" + $.jgrid.nav.cancelicon + "\"></span>");
}
```

I use here the icons defined as `editicon`, `delicon`, `saveicon` and `cancelicon` properties of `$.jgrid.nav`. The object `$.jgrid.nav` can be used to specify the default values of `navGrid` properties instead of usage the corresponding options of `navGrid`. Typically one includes just the line like

```js
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.nav, {
    editicon: "MyEditIconClass",
    addicon: "MyAddIconClass",
    searchicon: "MySearchIconClass",
    delicon: "MyDeleteIconClass",
    refreshicon: "MyRefreshIconClass",
    viewicon: "MyViewIconClass",
    saveicon: "MySaveIconClass",
    cancelicon: "MyCancelIconClass"
});
```

at the beginning of your code and all later calls of `navGrid` and `inlineNav` will uses the specified default values for the icons.

Comment: @JarretGibson: You are welcome! By the way I continue to develop *free* version of jqGrid on [my fork](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid) of jqGrid. The version of jqGrid do allow to change icons of `formatter: "actions"`. By default it uses the icons of navigator. So if you redefine icons by `$.extend(true, $.jgrid.nav, {...});` (for `navGrid` and `inlineNav`) then `formatter: "actions"` will automatically use the same icons.